# How to pivot chart 2 data types from a specific date in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, pivot-chart

I'm trying to do a dashboard which it looks fine, but I have one problem with a line chart.
I'll try to explain what I want to achieve.

I have a table like this:

```
| ID | Received Date | Completed Date | Status |
|----|---------------| ---------------|--------|
| 01 |   06/01/2022  |   08/01/2022   |Complete|
| 02 |   07/01/2022  |   10/01/2022   |Complete|
| 03 |   08/01/2022  |                | On hold|
| 04 |   09/01/2022  |   14/01/2022   |Complete|
| 05 |   10/01/2022  |   16/01/2022   |Complete|
| 06 |   11/01/2022  |                |In Prog.|
| 07 |   12/01/2022  |   20/01/2022   |Complete|
| 08 |   13/01/2022  |   22/01/2022   |Complete|
| 09 |   14/01/2022  |                |In Prog.|
| 10 |   15/01/2022  |   26/01/2022   |Complete|
```

In the example above, I want a line chart to show how many we received and completed each day/week/month/year.

So I expect the chart to show something like this if I want to filter by week:

```
| Week | Received | Completed |
|------|----------| ----------|
|  01  |    3     |     1     |
|  02  |    7     |     2     |
```

I update the data each day using a macro, and I have thousands of records. The dashboard shows who's the customers, who's the person in charge of that ID, etc. so if it is possible, I want this chart to work only with that table. Is this possible? All my data is stored in the Data Model of Excel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @xQbert Not 3 days but 3 records (Jan 6th, 7th & 8th), and you see that there is one record completed on Jan 8th only.

Answer (score 0):

**Please See The Bellow Mention Screenshot Use Week Formulas In Column D**

```
=WEEKDAY(C3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Weekday only brings you the day of the week in number. Also, you have completed date on the pendings ones, so it doesn't make sense. I want the week for each pending and each completed to be connected to another date

Comment: did not understand please explain